# Can we do source transformation for dependent sources?

Tags: passive-networks, network, network-interface, networking

In network analysis, during source transformation for dependent sources

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, show an example circuit.

Comment: If dependent voltage source in series with resistance, can we apply source transformation here

Comment: Surely we can. Why not?

Comment: Thanks, thought it's only applied for independent sources

Comment: There must be some condition to apply it, Is anyone know?

Comment: You better ask a specific question as noted in the first comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You better reply with answers rather than commenting one after the other.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, source transformation can be carried out for dependent sources much the same way for independent ones. Here right and left circuits are equivalent and can be used interchangeably.

[image]